Recursive triangle number program in MIPS
I'm working on a MIPS program that takes user input and returns a triangle number using a recursive algorithm. For example, Triangle(4) = 10, triangle (3) = 6. For the base case, triangle (1) =1. I've got most of it mapped out, but I keep receiving 1 as the result no matter the input, and am not sure what I can do to get it working.
The example algorithm:
Triangle( N <= 1 ) = 1
o Triangle( N > 1 ) = N + Triangle( N-1 )
o For example:
Triangle( 1 ) = 1
Triangle( 2 ) = 3
Triangle( 3 ) = 6
Triangle( 4 ) = 10

Here's what I have so far:
.data
    prompt:     .asciiz "Enter a positive integer (N): "
    result_msg: .asciiz "The triangle number is: "

.text
    main:
        # Prompt user input
        li $v0, 4         #  syscall code for print_str
        la $a0, prompt    # load address of prompt string
        syscall

        # Read user input
        li $v0, 5         # syscall code for read_int
        syscall
        move $s0, $v0     # store input

        # Call recursive subroutine
        move $a0, $s0     # pass N as an argument
        jal triangle

        # Print result
        li $v0, 4         #  syscall code for print_str
        la $a0, result_msg # load address of result_msg string
        syscall

        li $v0, 1         # syscall code for print_int
        move $a0, $v0     # print  result
        syscall

        # Exit
        li $v0, 10        # syscall code for exit
        syscall

    # Recursive subroutine to compute triangle numbers
    triangle:
        # Function prologue
        addi $sp, $sp, -8
        sw $ra, 4($sp)
        sw $a0, 0($sp)

        # Base case: Triangle(1) = 1
        li $t0, 1
        beq $a0, $t0, base_case

        # Recursive case: Triangle(N) = N + Triangle(N-1)
        addi $a0, $a0, -1   # N-1
        jal triangle        # recursive call
        lw $t1, 0($sp)      # retrieve Triangle(N-1) result
        add $v0, $a0, $t1   # N + Triangle(N-1)

        # Function epilogue
        lw $ra, 4($sp)
        lw $a0, 0($sp)
        addi $sp, $sp, 8
        jr $ra

    # Base case subroutine
    base_case:
        li $v0, 1           # return value 1 for base case
        j end_recursive

    # End of recursive subroutine
    end_recursive:
    jr $ra 


li $v0, 1; move $a0, $v0 will obviously always just print 1. I have a feeling of deja vu :)

I completely missed that haha, I fixed that and now am getting other results than just 1. Now I'm getting triangle (3) = 5 and triangle (4) = 7, which are both a bit off by the expected result. Is there anything I did wrong in my recursive step?

add $v0, $a0, $t1 should be add $v0, $v0, $t1

That was it, thank you! I hope you have a great day or night :)

Your base case fails to clean up the stack — this is bad.  If the code seems to work with that, it is luck.
Either also clean up tha stack for the base case or else don't set up the stack until after isolating the base case.
We must always (dynamically) pair stack allocation and deallocation.

While it doesn't hurt, it is improper to reload $a0 upon exit (function epiloge) as no caller should expect/rely on that.
To be clear, you're saving both $ra and $a0 for your function's own benefit, not for any caller's benefit.
